# How to change static variable value using ASM?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I started learning Java Agent few days ago. But documentation is not very good and beginners like me struggling to understand the basics. I created a basic multiplier class and export it to runnable jar using eclipse. Here is the code snippet.

**Main jar file:**

```
public class Multiplier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
            int y = 25;
            int z = x * y;

            System.out.println("Multiply of x*y = " + z);
    }
}
```

[Bytecode for above class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPD1v.png)

Now I want to manipulate the value of x from an agent. I tried to create the Agent class like this

**Agent:**

```
package myagent;

import org.objectweb.asm.*;
import java.lang.instrument.*;

public class Agent {

    public static void premain(final String agentArg, final Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("Agent Started");        
        int x_modified = 5;

        //Now How to push the new value (x_modified) to the multiplier class? 
        //I know I have to use ASM but can't figure it out how to do it.
        //Result should be 125

    }

}
```

**My Question**

How do I set the value of x from agent class to multiplier class using ASM?
Result should be 125.

Comment: In general I suggest you code an example of what you want in Java, compile it and ASMifier the code. This will give you a template of what you want. Many IDEs have a byte code ASMifier plugin which generates the code you need.

Comment: Sorry if I am not understand you correctely. I already mentioned the bytecode of multiplier class, please see the attached image.

Comment: So that is the byte code you need to change by reading it with ASM, modifying it using `Instrumentation` Obvously the byte code doesn't have the name of local variables so you will have to infer which value you need to be replacing. BTW What you propose is likely to be for more complicated than doing the same thing just about any other way.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I know that bytecode doesn't  know my variable name. and I know how bytecode work, but I cant find out the way how I change the bytecode value using ASM. in my case (bytecode) line no 7, bipush 10. please see the original attached image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing, your agent has to do, is [registering a `ClassFileTransformer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#addTransformer-java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer-). The first thing, the class file transformer should do in its `transform` method, is checking the arguments to find out whether the current request is about the class we’re interested in, to return immediately if not.

If we are at the class we want to transform, we have to process the incoming class file bytes to return a new byte array. You can use ASM’s [`ClassReader`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html) to process to incoming bytes and chain it to a [`ClassWriter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) to produce a new array:

```
import java.lang.instrument.*;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import org.objectweb.asm.*;

public class ExampleAgent implements ClassFileTransformer {
    private static final String TRANSFORM_CLASS = "Multiplier";
    private static final String TRANSFORM_METHOD_NAME = "main";
    private static final String TRANSFORM_METHOD_DESC = "([Ljava/lang/String;)V";

    public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new ExampleAgent());
    }

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> cl,
                            ProtectionDomain pd, byte[] classfileBuffer) {
        if(!TRANSFORM_CLASS.equals(className)) return null;

        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
        cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, cw) {
            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                                             String signature, String[] exceptions) {
                MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(
                                       access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
                if(name.equals(TRANSFORM_METHOD_NAME)
                && desc.equals(TRANSFORM_METHOD_DESC)) {
                    return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, mv) {
                        @Override
                        public void visitIntInsn(int opcode, int operand) {
                            if(opcode == Opcodes.BIPUSH && operand == 10) operand = 5;
                            super.visitIntInsn(opcode, operand);
                        }
                    };
                }
                return mv;
            }
        }, 0);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Note that by passing the `ClassWriter` to our custom `ClassVisitor`’s constructor and passing the `MethodVisitor` returned by the `super.visitMethod` invocation to our `MethodVisitor`’s constructor, we enable a chaining that reproduces the original class by default; all methods we’re not overriding will delegate to the specified `ClassWriter`/`MethodVisitor` reproducing the encountered artifact. Compare with [the tutorial about ASM’s event model](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html).

The example above enables an optimization by also passing the `ClassReader` instance to the `ClassWriter`’s constructor. This improves the efficiency of instrumenting a class when only making small changes, like we do here.

The crucial part is overriding `visitMethod` to return our custom `MethodVisitor` when we are at the “hot” method and overriding `visitIntInsn` to change the desired instruction. Note how these methods delegate to the `super` calls when not altering the behavior, just like the methods we didn’t override.

Comment: Thanks @Holger , But I am getting errors. please see the link [here](https://pastebin.com/dhCQHHLd)

Comment: Make sure that the ASM library is on the class path at runtime.

Comment: Thanks you are awasome, issue solved. accepting this as an answer. I have one more question, how do you access/modify the constant pool? Should I ask a separate question?

Comment: When using the ASM library, you don’t. ASM does all constant pool processing for you. This simplifies the code & member processing, e.g. you can simply say `visitLdcInsn("A string constant")` or `visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io.PrintStream;")` on a method visitor and ASM will do all necessary constant pool updates. On the other hand, when you want to do something like redirecting all class references to another, ASM is not the best tool as it forces you to update all actual uses of the type instead of allowing a mere pool transformation.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared x inside main method. So it's scope is local. That's why you can't change the value of x from any other class.

Comment: I want to modify the value of the x inside the JVM runtime. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @LEON The only way to alter `x` in `multiplier` is to alter the code which sets it i.e you have to modify the `multiplier` code. This cannot in another class the way you suggest.

Comment: then what is the uses of java agent or java instrument? I  think You can modify bytecode at runtime with the help of "ObjectWeb ASM". Can you please explain what is the uses of these? [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM) and [link](http://asm.ow2.org/)

Answer (score 0):

To use ASM you need a custom CodeWriter in a custom ClassWriter which you pass to a ClassReader. http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial.html This will allow you to visit all instructions in the code for each method.

In particular you will need to override the `visitIntInsn` method so when you see the first `BIPUSH` instruction in `main` you can replace the value 10, with what ever value you chose.

The output of ClassWriter is a byte[] which your Instrumentation will return instead of the original code at which point `x` will be whatever value you made it in the code.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, I already saw the documentation there, as I new to the all bytecode thing my understanding little clouded, If you can give some example, it will be very helpfull for me.