# IllegalArgumentException on ClassNode.accept() when passing in ClassWriter

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

The actual changes that I've made with the ClassNode seem to have worked (as far as I can tell) however when I go to write the file an IllegalArgumentException occurs on the line specified bellow. This doesn't make a lot of sense because ClassNode.accept() takes in a ClassVisitor instance and ClassWriter extends ClassVisitor, If anyone has some more experience with asm, help is appreciated.

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(stream);
classReader.accept(classNode, 0);

for (MethodNode methodNode : classNode.methods){
    for (AbstractInsnNode abstractInsnNode : methodNode.instructions.toArray()){
        if (abstractInsnNode.getOpcode() == Opcodes.LDC){
            LdcInsnNode ldc = (LdcInsnNode) abstractInsnNode;
            if (ldc.cst.toString().equals("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")){
                ldc.cst = Pattern.compile("");
            }
        }
    }
}

ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
classNode.accept(classWriter); //Error Ocurs on this line
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
outputStream.write(classWriter.toByteArray());
outputStream.close();
```

The full error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value 
    at org.objectweb.asm.SymbolTable.addConstant(SymbolTable.java:501)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitLdcInsn(MethodWriter.java:1290)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.LdcInsnNode.accept(LdcInsnNode.java:66)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:144)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:792)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:690)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:426)
    at dev.bodner.jack.Main.main(Main.java:105)
```

I'm using java 16 and asm 9.2

Comment: Unless one of the changes you made involved an `LdcInsnNode`, of course.

Comment: @Holger added java and asm version, also my changes did involve `LdcInsnNode` would that cause this problem?

Comment: You assign a `Pattern` object to the `LdcInsnNode`’s constant. That doesn’t work. You can’t load a `Pattern` object via `ldc` instruction—at least not this way. If you want to change the string, just assign the new string.

Comment: @Holger Ah I was just using toString as a way of determining what the base object was, is there a way to replace the old pattern object there with a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to instrument a statement like `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")`, you have to be aware that it will get compiled to the two instructions

```
ldc          "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"         // pushing the string constant to the stack
invokestatic java/util/regex/Pattern compile (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/regex/Pattern;
```

So, you only have to change the string pushed by the `ldc` instruction.

E.g.

```java
ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
try(FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
    ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(stream);
    classReader.accept(classNode, 0);
}

for (MethodNode methodNode: classNode.methods) {
    for (AbstractInsnNode abstractInsnNode: methodNode.instructions) {
        if (abstractInsnNode.getOpcode() == Opcodes.LDC) {
            LdcInsnNode ldc = (LdcInsnNode) abstractInsnNode;
            if (ldc.cst.equals("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")) {
                ldc.cst = ""; // the replacement string
            }
        }
    }
}

ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(0);
classNode.accept(classWriter);
try(FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
    outputStream.write(classWriter.toByteArray());
}
```

This will replace any occurrence of the instruction `ldc "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"`, regardless of how the string will be used. This might be sufficient for your use case, but if you want to make sure, you’re only changing a string immediately passed to `Pattern.compile`, you can change the loop’s body to

```java
if (node.getOpcode() == Opcodes.LDC && isPatternCompile(node.getNext())) {
    LdcInsnNode ldc = (LdcInsnNode) node;
    if (ldc.cst.equals("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")) {
        ldc.cst = ""; // the replacement string
    }
}
```

introducing the following helper method:

```java
private static boolean isPatternCompile(AbstractInsnNode n) {
    String expectedDesc;
    if(n.getOpcode() == Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC) {
        expectedDesc = "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/regex/Pattern;";
    }
    else { // check for Pattern.compile(String,int) with int constant
        switch(n.getOpcode()) { 
            default: return false;
            case Opcodes.LDC:
                if(!((((LdcInsnNode)n).cst) instanceof Integer)) return false;
            case Opcodes.ICONST_0: case Opcodes.ICONST_1: case Opcodes.ICONST_2:
            case Opcodes.ICONST_3: case Opcodes.ICONST_4: case Opcodes.ICONST_M1:
            case Opcodes.BIPUSH: case Opcodes.SIPUSH:
        }
        n = n.getNext();
        if(n.getOpcode() != Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC) return false;
        expectedDesc = "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/util/regex/Pattern;";
    }
    MethodInsnNode m = (MethodInsnNode) n;
    return m.name.equals("compile")
        && m.owner.equals("java/util/regex/Pattern")
        && m.desc.equals(expectedDesc);
}
```

Note that when you decide to just replace all occurrences of a particular string constant, i.e. without checking the subsequent instructions, you can do it directly with ASM’s Visitor API. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454118/2711488) contains an example of such a chaining of reader and writer which requires less memory and also might be faster than using the Tree API.