# How to modify a Java bytecode using org.ow2.asm 6.0

Tags: java

I was asked the following question in an interview:

Problem: You can't use Java reflection to set a private field value, there is no  setter or getter function.

Is there any other way?

Example class:

```
public class User2 {
    private String name;

    public String toString(){
        return "name : " + name;
    }
}
```

How can I change `name`?

---

I am a newcomer to the ASM framework.

I want use ASM to setter `name` field value and getter `name` field value.

Please don't use ASM create getter and setter function.

Comment: **Why** can't you use *reflection*? **Why** can't you add a *getter* or a *setter*? **Can** you add a constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use reflection"?

Comment: make that value public?

Comment: No setter, no constructor, no reflection. Well, you could instrument the bytecode using a Java agent.

Comment: this is Interview question.....

Comment: Are you conducting the interview or were you asked that question? Asking for a friend.

Comment: If you can't use setter or constructor then make `name` public : `public String name`

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is the standard way to achieve this. But there are also other ways:

Like [compile time steps](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/reflection-no-reflection), [debugging instruments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/instrumentation/index.html) ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848190/4265739)) or [flipping bits in ram physically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer).

If you have some library that has some private value you can decompile and edit it.

Or most obviously change the source code. Hint: make `public` or create `getName`

In the end it is code that gets linked and executed. During creation of the code, linking and execution there are several ways and means. If any of them is worth your while is your choice to make.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any byte code library(like ASM , BCEL, javaassit, etc) to add/remove/change the field (method also). Sample is given on this link [How to change static variable value using ASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334673/how-to-change-static-variable-value-using-asm).